# Spring boot or maven corrupts binary files, only in production

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, web, webassembly

In a project I work in here is a problem with binary static files (woff2 and wasm files) served with a Spring boot project from a webjar file are being corrupted, they are larger than they should be.

When the service is ran locally with mvn spring-boot:run the file size is correct and works fine, but in production the fonts and Web Assembly code cannot be used. The wasm file is 196287 bytes if I extract it from the jar file and that is exactly the same as in the development filesystem/repo. When served in production the file size of the downloaded file is 225201 and it will not compile the Web Assembly module.

I have seen several other issues related to maven corrupting files, but as the file size is correct when I extract the file possibly this is something else? We have been using maven-resources-plugin version 3.0.1 which is a bit outdated. We are trying to disabling filtering for binary types as described in https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/binaries-filtering.html .

```
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>build</directory>
        <targetPath>META-INF/resources</targetPath>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.1</version>
         <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                <nonFilteredFileExtension>ttf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff2</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                <nonFilteredFileExtension>eot</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                <nonFilteredFileExtension>wasm</nonFilteredFileExtension>            
           </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
         </configuration>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

I'm thinking if Spring boot when in dev mode actually reads the mime type of a file and in production assumes everything is UTF-8 text, thereby corrupting the binary files? This should then be a common problem for may projects?

Any thoughts on how to debug this further?

Update: Attached below is the first point where the files differ (from vbindiff), it's a bit beyond my skills to read anything out of this but maybe someone else can.

```
pulldown_cmark_wasm_bg.wasm                                                                                                                                                                                                     
0000 0190: 06 89 80 80 80 00 01 7F  01 41 80 80 C0 00 0B 07  ........ .A......                                                                                                                                                  
0000 01A0: D1 80 80 80 00 05 06 6D  65 6D 6F 72 79 02 00 06  .......m emory...                                                                                                                                                  
0000 01B0: 66 6F 72 6D 61 74 00 32  11 5F 5F 77 62 69 6E 64  format.2 .__wbind                                                                                                                                                  
0000 01C0: 67 65 6E 5F 6D 61 6C 6C  6F 63 00 9C 01 12 5F 5F  gen_mall oc....__                                                                                                                                                  
0000 01D0: 77 62 69 6E 64 67 65 6E  5F 72 65 61 6C 6C 6F 63  wbindgen _realloc                                                                                                                                                  
0000 01E0: 00 A1 01 0F 5F 5F 77 62  69 6E 64 67 65 6E 5F 66  ....__wb indgen_f                                                                                                                                                  
0000 01F0: 72 65 65 00 B4 01 09 F4  80 80 80 00 01 00 41 01  ree..... ......A.                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0200: 0B 3E B5 01 B6 01 08 B9  01 B2 01 7B 29 B1 01 D6  .>...... ...{)...                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0210: 01 80 01 95 01 97 01 1F  CB 01 C8 01 CD 01 26 4D  ........ ......&M                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0220: 83 01 CC 01 BA 01 BB 01  81 01 BC 01 37 47 CE 01  ........ ....7G..                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0230: 92 01 D0 01 38 CF 01 AA  01 D5 01 87 01 D4 01 86  ....8... ........                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0240: 01 D3 01 94 01 D2 01 39  D1 01 85 01 A0 01 D7 01  .......9 ........                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0250: AC 01 D8 01 53 D9 01 B3  01 40 82 01 DA 01 DB 01  ....S... .@......                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0260: CA 01 DC 01 8B 01 DD 01  17 B0 01 11 BD 01 AE 01  ........ ........                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0270: 0A CC 8E 87 80 00 DE 01  D0 7A 02 2E 7F 03 7E 23  ........ .z....~#                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0280: 00 41 D0 04 6B 22 03 24  00 02 40 02 40 02 40 20  .A..k".$ ..@.@.@                                                                                                                                                   
0000 0290: 02 41 05 76 22 04 41 80  01 20 04 41 80 01 4B 1B  .A.v".A. . .A..K.                                                                                                                                                  
0000 02A0: 22 05 41 05 74 22 06 41  7F 4C 0D 00 02 40 20 06  ".A.t".A .L...@ .                                                                                                                                                  
0000 02B0: 41 08 10 BE 01 22 04 45  0D 00 20 04 42 00 37 03  A....".E .. .B.7.                                                                                                                                                  
0000 02C0: 10 20 04 41 20 3A 00 00  20 04 41 18 6A 42 00 37  . .A :..  .A.jB.7                                                                                                                                                  
0000 02D0: 03 00 20 03 41 F0 01 6A  41 AC BD C0 00 10 8C 01  .. .A..j A.......                                                                                                                                                  
0000 02E0: 20 03 29 03 F8 01 21 31  20 03 29 03 F0 01 21 32   .)...!1  .)...!2                                                                                                                                                  
0000 02F0: 02 40 41 80 1C 41 04 10  BE 01 22 06 45 0D 00 20  .@A..A.. ..".E..                                                                                                                                                   
0000 0300: 03 41 80 02 6A 41 F0 00  6A 42 80 80 80 80 20 37  .A..jA.. jB.... 7                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0310: 03 00 20 03 41 E8 02 6A  42 00 37 03 00 20 03 41  .. .A..j B.7.. .A                                                                                                                                                  
pulldown_cmark_wasm_bg.wasm-corrupt                                                                                                                                                                                             
0000 0190: BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD  EF BF BD 00 01 70 01 3F  ........ .....p.?                                                                                                                                                  
0000 01A0: 3F 05 EF BF BD EF BF BD  EF BF BD EF BF BD 00 01  ?....... ........                                                                                                                                                  
0000 01B0: 00 11 06 EF BF BD EF BF  BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 00  ........ ........                                                                                                                                                  
0000 01C0: 01 7F 01 41 EF BF BD EF  BF BD EF BF BD 00 0B 07  ...A.... ........                                                                                                                                                  
0000 01D0: D1 80 EF BF BD EF BF BD  00 05 06 6D 65 6D 6F 72  ........ ...memor                                                                                                                                                  
0000 01E0: 79 02 00 06 66 6F 72 6D  61 74 00 32 11 5F 5F 77  y...form at.2.__w                                                                                                                                                  
0000 01F0: 62 69 6E 64 67 65 6E 5F  6D 61 6C 6C 6F 63 00 EF  bindgen_ malloc..                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0200: BF BD 01 12 5F 5F 77 62  69 6E 64 67 65 6E 5F 72  ....__wb indgen_r                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0210: 65 61 6C 6C 6F 63 00 EF  BF BD 01 0F 5F 5F 77 62  ealloc.. ....__wb                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0220: 69 6E 64 67 65 6E 5F 66  72 65 65 00 EF BF BD 01  indgen_f ree.....                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0230: 09 F4 80 80 80 00 01 00  41 01 0B 3E EF BF BD 01  ........ A..>....                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0240: EF BF BD 01 08 EF BF BD  01 EF BF BD 01 7B 29 EF  ........ .....{).                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0250: BF BD 01 EF BF BD 01 EF  BF BD 01 EF BF BD 01 EF  ........ ........                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0260: BF BD 01 1F EF BF BD 01  EF BF BD 01 EF BF BD 01  ........ ........                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0270: 26 4D EF BF BD 01 EF BF  BD 01 EF BF BD 01 EF BF  &M...... ........                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0280: BD 01 EF BF BD 01 EF BF  BD 01 37 47 EF BF BD 01  ........ ..7G....                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0290: EF BF BD 01 EF BF BD 01  38 EF BF BD 01 EF BF BD  ........ 8.......                                                                                                                                                  
0000 02A0: 01 EF BF BD 01 EF BF BD  01 EF BF BD 01 EF BF BD  ........ ........                                                                                                                                                  
0000 02B0: 01 EF BF BD 01 EF BF BD  01 EF BF BD 01 39 EF BF  ........ .....9..                                                                                                                                                  
0000 02C0: BD 01 EF BF BD 01 EF BF  BD 01 EF BF BD 01 EF BF  ........ ........                                                                                                                                                  
0000 02D0: BD 01 EF BF BD 01 53 EF  BF BD 01 EF BF BD 01 40  ......S. .......@                                                                                                                                                  
0000 02E0: EF BF BD 01 EF BF BD 01  EF BF BD 01 EF BF BD 01  ........ ........                                                                                                                                                  
0000 02F0: EF BF BD 01 EF BF BD 01  EF BF BD 01 17 EF BF BD  ........ ........                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0300: 01 11 EF BF BD 01 EF BF  BD 01 0A CC 8E EF BF BD  ........ ........                                                                                                                                                  
0000 0310: EF BF BD 00 EF BF BD 01  EF BF BD 7A 02 2E 7F 03  ........ ...z....                                                                                                                                                  
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐                                                                                                                                                
│Arrow keys move  F find      RET next difference  ESC quit  T move top        │                                                                                                                                                
│C ASCII/EBCDIC   E edit file   G goto position      Q quit  B move bottom     │                                                                                                                                                
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was a combination of the headers that the Nginx reverse proxy in front and the Spring Boot service created in combination. The Node.js services did not have the same problem.

I'm not sure how this was eventually solved and probably some information was missing in the question so I'll close this question now.

Comment: Might have been related to compression and content length headers that messed up the response body when passed through the Nginx reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe filtering is enabled for those binary files and in prod build it does replace by mistake some data in binary files.

Maybe try to run diff to compare what has changed in those binary files?

Comment: Thanks, I have extracted the files from the webjar and confirmed that those has the original size, it's the ones served from the build service that is corrupted (larger) when downloaded. I guess I could try to find use some binary diff tool to try to see if that gives any clues.

Comment: I attached the first diff to the question, it's a bit beyond my skills to read anything useful from I'm afraid, but maybe someone else can.